# css media queries - is this a bad way to implement?

Tags: css, media-queries

I recently asked a question about how to use media queries while supporting fallback for older browsers that don't support them. The only answer (while it works) was to use javascript such as adapt.js to determine which stylesheet to load.

I have been tinkering around and realized an unbelieveably simple solution that worked for me in IE7 anyways, was the following:

```
.wrapper{width:1024px;}

@media all and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .wrapper{width:1024px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .wrapper{width:1024px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px){
    .wrapper{width:900px;}
}
```

The above is just a really simple example. When I fiddling around I noticed if I specified a default value for .wrapper IE7 rendered it and ignored the media queries. In Chrome/FF/Safari it used the media queries css. This leads me to think this can be a compatible workaround to javaascript but I'm not sure of any ramifications whether browser compatibility or SEO.

Is this a bad way to implement and will it have any compatibility issues? I like the idea of having all css in one file.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi Joe, have you looked into [mobile-first Responsive CSS design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ordering of `max-width` media queries means that by the cascade, this rule becomes totally unnecessary; you can remove it unless you intend the styles in this rule to be different than your first rule which doesn't sit in its own `@media` block:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .wrapper{width:1024px;}
}
```

Besides that, I don't see any ramifications or compatibility issues. It's pretty much how media queries with `@media` rules are meant to be used.